# UITableView with UIToolBar

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I have UITableView being pushed to UINavigationController. I need to add a UIToolBar to that tableView. Toolbar has to have two buttons. After pressing each of them tableView will show different types of data, sections and cells.

UITableView has header view and i need it to stay whyle tableView itself changes.

What is the right way to implement this logics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UIToolBar and your UITableView can be composed together inside the ViewController, the UIToolBar does not need to be a child view of your UITableView.      If your ViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController you may need to switch to a simple UIViewController parent, so you can add both the tool bar and the table within the view.

That way the toolbar does not scroll with the table.

Comment: Allright. Got it! Thanks. Thats exactly what i've been looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bogatyr, was very helpful, initially thought it was a tedious task moving from UITableViewController to UIViewController, but it wasn't to be. Just had to conform to the protocols UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource. Thanks again !!

Comment: Yes if you're just using a basic table's functionality then there's no  reason to use UITableViewController.   But there is advanced functionality, like the integrated search controller, where if you don't use UITableViewController you end up reinventing a pretty big wheel.